# Create 4 new divs of same class inside parent div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to make a program that starts off with 4 square divs in a grid.

When a mouse enters a div I would like its background colour to become white and for 4 new divs to fit neatly inside (2 on the top 2 on the bottom).

The code I have written however wont calcualte the height/width value needed to make the child divs and instead just adds 4 small divs to the original. Think there may be a problem with me using a class to select the element?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    makeGrid();
    $("#wrapper").on("mouseenter",".cell",function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","white"); 
        var childCellLenght = $(this).width/2;

        var $childDiv = $("<div>", {
            class: "cell", 
            width: childCellLenght,
            height:childCellLenght,
            backgroundColor:get_random_color
        });
        for(var i =0; i<4;i++){    
            $(this).append($childDiv.clone());
        }
    });
});
```

[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04du5L72/1/)

Comment: a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code would  be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for. Use CSS to define styles early then append would be lot easier

```js
//Javascript
makeGrid();//first instance

$(".wrapper").on("mouseenter",".cell",function(){
  var curCell = $(this);
  if(checkThreshold(curCell)){
    return false;
  }
  for(var i =0; i<4;i++){
    curCell.append($("<div>", {
         class: "cell", 
         css:{
            'background-color':'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
         }
      })
    );
  }
});

function makeGrid(){
  $(".wrapper").append('<div class=cell></div><div class=cell></div><div class=cell></div><div class=cell></div>');
}

function checkThreshold(n){
  var threshold = 5;//change this to how many levels of nested divs you want (-1 for infinite divs)
  if(threshold===-1){
    return false;
  }
  var counter = 0;
  while(!n.parent().hasClass('wrapper')){
    n = n.parent();
    ++counter;
  }
  return counter>=threshold;
}
```

```css
/* CSS for parent and subsequent children */
div.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  height:400px;
  background-color:#abcdef;
}

div.wrapper div.cell{
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML snippet -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=wrapper></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, they finaly fit in properly! :D Do you know how i would go about making each child div split into 4 on mouse over? So the squeres get samller and smaller?

Comment: Added the snippet based on your requirement, else if you remove the threshold to `var threshold = -1` it will keep on adding infinite divs to respective children. I hope you have a level to which you want it to happen put that number to `threshold = <your final limit>`

Comment: Thanks so much, not only do  I have a cool thing to play with, Ive also leaned a lot from from your code!